# React SetState doesn't call render

Tags: reactjs, callback, render, setstate

I send my function to child component for `callBack`. In the parent, I have a function with `setState` method:

```
onInputUpdated(id){
  var array = {};
  let char = id.slice(-1);
  console.log(this.state.states)
  switch(char){
    case 'a':
      array[id] = this.getY(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[id].refs.inp).value);
      break;
    case 'b':
      array[id] = this.getX(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[id].refs.inp).value);
      break;
  }

  let oldStates = this.state.states;
  oldStates[id] = array[id];

  this.setState({
    states: oldStates
  });
  console.log(oldStates);
}
```

Where `states` is an object.

After this, `states` is set. I can see it in the next `callBack`, where I have print to console. However, the `render` method isn't invoked. During `componentMount`, everything is rendered correctly.

What to do? Thanks.

Comment: "What to do", "to mount everything right"... etc - they are not correct questions to be asked on StackOverflow. Please, spend some time editing your question in correspondence to the input from the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `let oldStates = this.state.states;` you're just making `oldStates` variable a reference to `this.state.states`, so you're effectively changing the state before you call `setState`.

Try to make a copy of it instead, for example `let oldStates = Object.assign({}, this.state.states`, or use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) or something similar if you need a deep clone.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are setting it and then settings it back again. Try and create a brand new instance of the object. Here is how to do it with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

First make sure you run the following . . .

```
npm install --save underscore
```

And then import underscore . . .

```
import _ from 'underscore';
```

and then clone the object.

```
let oldStates = _.clone(this.state.states);
```