# React: useState filter array not updating state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

**Edit:**

My error occured because I passed an array as a second parameter to `useEffect`. Even though the values inside the array stayed the same, the reference changed constantly, therefore `useEffect` was called constantly and reset my checkbox values. That array was created by an `useState` call. I replaced `useState` by `useReducer` (reducer only changes the object reference if the object is actually changed) and updated some missing dependencies higher up the component tree.

**Original question:**

I have trouble updating a state in a functional component.

My question is somewhat similiar to this one:
[React SetState doesn't call render](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38477917/7080781)

I'm already copying my state object (by using array.filter) instead of referencing it; but my state still doesn't update.

In order to track down the problem, I tried re-creating the problem in a minimal example:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbsy9fkm/)

But in my minimal example, everything works as expected. I'm unable to reproduce the error.

Here is my example where the state doesn't update:

configCheckboxGroup.tsx:

```
import classNames from "classnames";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Component } from "../../model";
import CheckboxPanel from "./panels/checkboxPanel";

interface configCheckboxGroupProps {
    className?: string;
    choices: Array<Component>;
    selected: Array<string>;
    addToCart: (items: Array<Component>) => void;
}

const ConfigCheckboxGroup: React.SFC<configCheckboxGroupProps> = ({
    className,
    choices,
    selected,
    addToCart,
}) => {

    const [ selectedComp, setSelectedComp ] = useState<Array<string>>(selected);

    // device loads later, selected has to be updated
    useEffect(() => {
        setSelectedComp(selected);
    }, [selected]);

    const handleOnChange = (ev: React.FormEvent, id: string) => {
        console.debug(id);
        console.debug(selectedComp.filter(el => el !== id));
        if (selectedComp.includes(id)) {
            // was already checked || this line is not working!
            setSelectedComp(selectedComp.filter(el => el !== id));
        } else {
            // was not checked
            setSelectedComp([...(selectedComp), id]);
        }

        const selected = choices.filter(el => selectedComp.includes(el.reference._id));
        addToCart(selected);        
    };

    return (
        <div className={classNames("panellist", className)}>
        {
            choices.map(el => {
                return (
                    <CheckboxPanel 
                        image={ el.reference.picture ? el.reference.picture : undefined }
                        name={ el.reference.name }
                        id={ el.reference._id }
                        price={ el.reference.price ? el.reference.price : 
                            el.price ? el.price : 0 } 
                        key={ el._id }
                        checked={ selectedComp.includes(el.reference._id) }  
                        onChange={ handleOnChange }
                    />
                )
            })
        }
        <span>
        { selectedComp }
            </span>
            </div>
    )
}

export default ConfigCheckboxGroup;
```

And checkboxPanel.tsx:

```
import classNames from "classnames";
import React from "react";

import "./checkboxPanel.scss";

import noImage from "../../../resources/images/errors/no-image.svg";

interface PanelProps {
    className?: string;
    image?: string;
    name: string;
    id: string;
    price: number;
    checked: boolean;
    onChange: (ev: React.FormEvent, id: string) => void;
}

const CheckboxPanel: React.SFC<PanelProps> = ({
    className,
    image,
    name,
    id,
    price,
    checked,
    onChange,
}) => {

    const getImage = () => {
        if (image) {
            return image;
        } else {
            return noImage;
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={classNames("panel", "checkbox-panel", className)}>
            <div className="top">
                <div className="image">
                    <img alt="Product" src={getImage()} />
                </div>
                <div className="name">
                    {name}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="bottom">
                <div className="category">
                    { Number(price).toFixed(2) } €
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" 
                        checked={ checked }
                        onChange={ (e) => onChange(e, id) }
                    />                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

};

export default CheckboxPanel;
```

The only difference between the examples is that in the second one, I call the handle function inside a child component. But I do the same thing on other occasions as well: I have a very similar Component configRadioGroup with radio buttons instead of checkboxes where everything works fine.

I tried playing around by manually filtering the array and trying a lot of other things, but nothing seemed to help. This is why, as a last try, I ask here (although I know that this question is not a good one due to it being very specific).

Comment: Changing the prop `selected` will reset `selectedComp` if you put a console log in your useEffect you may find that that is resetting it every time.

Comment: You're right!
Altough I don't know why it is resetting; `selected` should only update once, when my data is loaded and the default status is set. I guess I'll have to track that further down.

Comment: But you still solved my issue (I didn't even think about that `useEffect` line); if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You need to track down where selected comes from (redux?) and how it's set (addToCart?)

Comment: the weird thing is: if I `console.debug(selected)`inside the `useEffect`, it always outputs the same string. Shouldn't `useEffect` only be called, if the second parameter changes?

Comment: I think `selected` is an array or object (reference value) not a string (primitive value) and `selected` is changed by the reducer or whatever `addToCart` causes to happen. You are right that useEffect would not be called if `selected` didn't change but in JS `{}!=={}` meaning that `{}` does not equal `{}` because it's a different reference.

Comment: Another thing that can cause the useEffect to be called again is that the component is unmounted and re mounted (loading screen between changing the selection?)

Comment: Selected is indeed an array. I didn't know that about JS.

I guess that I will change it to a primitive string, but just out of curiosity: How could I realize a `useEffect` that is called each time an array changes?

Comment: You should fix the problem at it's source, I suspect it's something that `addToCart` does or see where `selected` comes from `<ConfigCheckboxGroup selected={???}`

Comment: `<ConfigCheckboxGroup 
                    choices={ device ? device.steamLances : [] }
                    selected={ findManyDefaults(device ? device.steamLances : []) }
                    addToCart={ (items: Array<Component>) => addGroupToCart("steamLances", items) }
                />`



`findManyDefaults` filters an array for all elements that have `default` set to true. `selected` is an empty array as long as my database data isn't loaded; afterwards, it's an array with all elements that shall be selected by default.

Comment: For empty value try : `const EMPTY=[]` just under your imports and use that for when device is undefined: `selected={ findManyDefaults(device ? device.steamLances : EMPTY) }`. Now instead of `[]!==[]` you get `EMPTY===EMPTY`. It now depends what `findManyDefaults` does to make a new reference for selected when device is defined.

Comment: I solved my problem by using JSON.stringify to convert my array into a string and using JSON.parse to convert it back into an array. Currently it is working as expected. As I consider my solution somewhat hacky and not very clean, I will try out your suggestion, but most likely on another occasion. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It all depends on what `findManyDefaults` does. I think you can solve it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the prop `selected` will reset `selectedComp` if you put a console log in your useEffect you may find that that is resetting it every time.

You need to track down where selected comes from (redux?) and how it's set (addToCart?).

A dirty fix could be to only set `selectedComp` when component mounts, this is dirty and will/should cause react-hooks/exhaustive-deps lint to trigger:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setSelectedComp(selected);
}, []);
```

But better to track down what's going wrong with `selected`, if it comes from redux then maybe just use `selected` instead and forget about `selectedComp` since that is just a copy.